# submitting a form which is being called via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that will be generated by ajax via an ajax request, when i try to submit the said form nothing really happens. any idea as to why this is happening?

by my logic it should work since the form is not in the same page as my another ajax function that was made to submit it.

anyway here are my codes:

ajax that will create the form:

```
$(".editschool").change(function(){
var eschl = $(".editschool").val();
$.ajax({url:"update.php", 
data: {schoolid: eschl},
type:'post',
async: false,
success: function(data){
$('#vupdate').html(data);
$('#vupdate').show();
},
});
});
```

the form:

```
$form .= '<form class="form-add" id="udata" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $form .= '
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uschoolname" name="uschoolname" value = "'.$sname.'" placeholder="Name of School">
            </div>';
        $form .= '
            <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="uschoolabout" name="uschoolabout" placeholder="About the School">'.$sabout.'</textarea>
            </div>';
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="sid" value = "'.$sid.'">';
        $form .= '
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Syllabus</label>
        <input type="file" id="ufile" name="ufile">
        <p class="help-block">File type: png, jpg, jpeg, gif</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>';
        $form .= '</form>';
```

the other ajax that will submit the form:

```
$("#udata").submit(function(){
                console.log("test");
                var formData1 = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData1,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data == "1"){
                            $("#uschoolname").val("");
                            $("#uschoolabout").val("");
                            $("#ufile").val("");
                        }
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
                return false;
            });
```

note that my console is clean of any errors.

Comment: Are you calling that last block of code after the form has been received?

Comment: the 2 ajax scripts are already called prior to retrieving the form, the answer below did the trick though i could really use an explanation as to how is it different from .submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing the

```
$("#udata").submit(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on("submit", "#udata", function(){})
```

Comment: great that worked! though why and how is it different from the .submit function?

Comment: The .submit function will work only if we call that function after the  ajax generated form is loaded. Otherwise we need to use $(document).on("submit")